# tegra android development pack downloading during installation error windows 8.1 (64 bit)

Tags: android, failed-installation, tegra

Same error on versions

- tadp-3.0r3-windows
- tadp-3.0r2-windows
- tadp-2.0r8-windows

`TADP (Tegra Android Development Pack)` installer was downloaded from official website flawlessly.

During the installation the installer downloads files, which in this case fails to finish downloading the files required to install the `TADP`.

The downloading stops at `236MB` and fails in 10 attempts to reconnect and download.

Then i get the following error:

```
Error running E:\NVPACK\_installer\DownloadHelper.exe
http://dl-google.com/android/repository/platform_tools_r20-windows.zip -t
"Download SDK platform Tools" -r 10 -c
72c34cc... many numbers..30f9--use_md5 0;program
ended with an exit code
```

Answer (score 1):

**tadp-2.0-r7-windows (64 bit) is working!**
only down side is that it has NDK R9 b and older set of tools like openCV 2.4.5